# WeatherAPI responses

Tags: asp.net

As part of my project **WeatherDataSharingSystem**, I need to get response(json/xml format) from different APIs. For that I need url that gives response from API. I get the url of *OpenWeatherMap API*(url: openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?q=trivandrum) which give weather forecasting response. I need the url of *WorldWeatherOnline* which gives the weather forecasting response.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: not giving up I see - possible duplicate of [Weather Forecasting API responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793115/weather-forecasting-api-responses)

Comment: Why this question is not answered??

Comment: Nobody have experience with Weather APIs???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url which give json response for weather forecast are:

[openweathermap](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?q=trivandrum)

[worldweatheronline](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?format=json&num_of_days=1&key=YOUR_APIKEY&q=trivandrum,India&date=2013-04-07)

[aerisapi](http://api.aerisapi.com//forecasts/trivandrum,India??filter=14&client_id=YOURCLIENTID&client_secret=YOURCLIENTSECRET)